# regex pattern to match string in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, pattern-matching, nsregularexpression

Here is a regex pattern I created in Objective C:

```
^\n?([#]{1,2}$|[*]{1,2}$|[0-9]{1,3}.$)
```

I want to match:

1. starts with \n or empty
2. ends with # or * or .
3. if ends with . there will be 1 or 2 or 3 digits in between
4. If ends with # or *, there could be 1 more # or * in between

The regex I created matches '\n1#' which is not what I want. 
Can anyone help me correct this? Is this fastest one? The regex will be used frequently, so I want it to be as fast as possible.

UPDATE:

Here's a sample strings for testing:

```
"\n#", "11*1", "1#", "a1.", "111*", "\n1#", "\n11.", "a11.", "1. ", "*1."
```

The `1#` and `111*` were matched. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Isn't item #1, "Starts with \n or empty" useless?  A string that starts with \n is nothing more than an empty line.  Instead just search for the string you are looking for with an explicit '^' at the start of your regex.  it will simplify the regex just a little bit.

Comment: @SlyRaskal Makes Sense, thanks. Do you know what's the problem with the rest?

Comment: Studying it now, don't know if what I'm coming up with will work though.

Comment: Could you post up some sample strings to test against?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on what type of characters should be present when a # or * is at the end.  I think that's the problem.  Is it that there shouldn't be any numbers but it can be any other character if it ends with # or *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're matching `#1` and `111#` because of `[0-9]{1,3}.`. You haven't escaped the `.` and this group basically matches any sequence of 1 to 3 digits followed by any character.

What you're looking for is

```
^\n?(#{1,2}|\*{1,2}|[0-9]{1,3}\.)$
```

Properly escaped in ObjC, it would be

```
@"^\n?(#{1,2}|\\*{1,2}|[0-9]{1,3}\\.)$"
```

If this regex is used quite a lot, you might want to cache the `NSRegularExpression` object to avoid compiling it everytime.

[Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is very useful to test regular expressions.

Comment: I was just about to answer the question myself. I got warning when I added one \. Objective-C requires you to add two \. Thanks.